# ElasticSearch field showing as bad string, causes error when searched

Tags: php, elasticsearch, sense

I have a problem with data in elasticsearch, basically I need to store the userID that owns the documents below, I can search fine on anything aside from the userID if I view the data in sense I get a "bad string" error on the userID field.

Whats going on?

```
   {"took":1,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":3,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"pheme","_type":"searches","_id":"AU__X0W7bLxGTuBqZB_E","_score":1.0,"_source":{
      userID: "AU__X0W7bLxGTuBqZB_E", **<---- This shows as bad string in Sense**
      mustHave: "Laravel",
      notHave: "Moogle",
      couldHave: "AngularJS",
      exclusions: {
        ID : ""
      }
    }
    },{"_index":"pheme","_type":"searches","_id":"AU__ZNA0bLxGTuBqZCCn","_score":0.30685282,"_source":{
      userID: "AU__X0W7bLxGTuBqZB_E",
      mustHave: "Laravel",
      notHave: "Moogle",
      couldHave: "AngularJS",
      exclusions: {
        ID : ""
      }
    }
    },{"_index":"pheme","_type":"searches","_id":"AVAJl5OZbMFoS2ut2YM9","_score":0.30685282,"_source":{
          userID: "AU__X0W7bLxGTuBqZB_E",
          mustHave: "Laravel",
          notHave: "Moogle",
          couldHave: "AngularJS",
          exclusions: {
            ID : ""
          }
        }
        }]}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem lay in the way the data was being created if you notice in my sample above the field names are missing surrounding quotes:

```
  {"took":1,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":3,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"pheme","_type":"searches","_id":"AU__X0W7bLxGTuBqZB_E","_score":1.0,"_source":{
      userID: "AU__X0W7bLxGTuBqZB_E", **<---- This shows as bad string in Sense**
      mustHave: "Laravel",
      notHave: "Moogle",
      couldHave: "AngularJS",
      exclusions: {
        ID : ""
      }
    }
    }
```

SHOULD BE

```
 {"took":1,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":3,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"pheme","_type":"searches","_id":"AU__X0W7bLxGTuBqZB_E","_score":1.0,"_source":{
      "userID": "AU__X0W7bLxGTuBqZB_E", **<---- This shows as bad string in Sense**
      "mustHave": "Laravel",
      "notHave": "Moogle",
      "couldHave": "AngularJS",
      "exclusions": {
        "ID" : ""
      }
    }
    }
```

It's important to note that Sense under marvel doesn't stop you inserting invalid data and that Elastic will simply output that data to whatever client your using, under PHP this will cause JsonExceptionError because the invalid json can't be encoded into an array.

Also I was doing the parent/child relationship wrong, there's no need to have a field for the userID when inserting the record you simply specify the parent then query using has_parent/filter.